# Not completely switching language in Midnight Commander

Tags: ubuntu, locale, mc

spent a lot of time on this.
All menu bars and control panel at the bottom are not translated.

What I did:

- set the locale globally to the desired language, even tried LC_ALL
- reinstalled mc and mc-data
- installed language-pack and language-pack base
- I searched for the locale file in /usr/share/local/language/ and there was a file mc.mo there
- I copied mc.mo to different language directories
- I tried running mc with LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8 mc
- set LANG variables in ~/.bashrc
- rebooted the server, source bashrc
- update and upgrade
- I even tried some answers from GPT (xd) they were quite trivial.
- used `apt-get install --reinstall locales` and `dpkg-reconfigure locales`

Works:

- The right language in the hints and inside the "File listing" dates have the right language
- man page translated into the desired language
- help is also in the required language, but the translation was found in /usr/share/ms/help

don't know what to do at all
Ubuntu 20.04 (almost clean install) pre-installed HestiaCP / mc 4.8.24

> Note: the other language doesn't work either